# Is it possible to hide the error message when an Android service is crashed

Tags: android, service

I have a bound service in separate process. It crashes occasionally due to the oem native libs on certain phones. I am trying to make the app recover from it.

I would like to silently restart the service and continue the workflow. But it seems the error message is always displayed after the service is crashed. Is there a way to suppress the error? We can handle the unhanded java exception, but not sure how to handle the native crash.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. Handle the sig works for me.